# A hashrate of 1.42 EH/s, really?

Tags: mining-hardware, mining-theory, hashpower, gpu-mining

According to http://bravenewcoin.com/news/number-of-bitcoin-miners-far-higher-than-popular-estimates/ there are 100,000 miners and blockchain.info claims a hashrate of **1.42 EH/s**.

How is it possible to be mining on Bitcoin at a hashrate of 1.42 EH/s with just 100,000 miners?

That would yield 14.2 TH/s per miner, while best ASICs are performing around **1 TH/s** https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mining_hardware_comparison

Comment: From the chart you posted, the best ASIC on the chart is the Antminer S5+ which yields 7.7 TH/s.

Comment: Right, but I guess not every miner is using Antminer S5+...

Comment: A a single miner could be using 200 Antminer S5+ units though

Comment: It's not really clear from that article whether a "miner" refers to a device, or a person, or an organization, or what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A miner should not be correlated with a device. I can have 10 devices and I will still be a single miner from the perspective of the pool. I can have a mining farm with thousand devices and I can still look like a single miner to the pool.

Also note that a miner, in the above sense, is just a person that provides hashing power to a pool that runs a mining node; i.e. there are much less mining nodes.